# django csrf_token missing error

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

When I am trying to register, I'm getting an error:

> Forbidden (403)
>   CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

My Code:

```
@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("firstname")
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get("lastname")
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password)
            user.first_name = first_name
            user.last_name = last_name
            user.set_password(password)
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render_to_response('registration/registerHome.html',dict(form=form,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request) ) )
```

my form.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    """
    A registration form to create normal user.
    """
    firstname = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\[a-zA-Z]+$',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'required':True,
            'max_length':30,
            'autocomplete':'off',
            'class':'form-control input-sm',
            'placeholder':'First Name' }),
        error_messages={ 'invalid': _("Only alphabets are allowed.") }
        )
    lastname = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\[a-zA-Z]+$',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'required':True,
            'max_length':30,
            'autocomplete':'off',
            'class':'form-control input-sm',
            'placeholder':'Last Name' }),
        error_messages={ 'invalid': _("Only alphabets are allowed.") }
        )
    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\w+$',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required':True,
            'max_length':30,
            'autocomplete':'off',
            'class':'form-control input-sm',
            'placeholder':'username'}),
        error_messages={ 'invalid': _("Only [a-z A-Z 0-9 _] are allowed.") }
        )
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'required':True,
            'max_length':30,
            'autocomplete':'off',
            'class':'form-control input-sm',
            'placeholder':'password',
            'render_value':False })
            )

    def clean_username(self):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Username already exists."))

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

my template.html

```
<form action="." method="post" role="form" id="register-form">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form.as_p }}
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                        </form>
```

Someone, please help me, why I'm getting an error. I am trying to solve this problem for 1 week and still getting the error. Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure the CsrfViewMiddleware is added in your settings file?

Comment: Yeah. 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',in setting.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `render` and add `else`

Then do like

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("firstname")
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get("lastname")
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password)
            user.first_name = first_name
            user.last_name = last_name
            user.set_password(password)
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'registration/registerHome.html',dict(form=form)))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/registerHome.html',dict(form=form)))
```

Comment: I tried. But now form.is_valid() is not working. I mean,
form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid(): not true.

Comment: not working means ? any error or if it returns False, try to print `form.errors` in else condition.

Comment: static error: RegistrationFrom has no attribute error.
I mean, from.error has the error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the @csrf_protect decorator as long as the csrf middleware is added.The Middleware gives you blanket protection on all views - adding the decorator is redundant. The Django docs recommend using the Middleware over the decorator as it provides better protection.

Try after removing the decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I remember sometime ago I had the same problem and declaring the `c` dictionary and passing it to the `render_to_response` solved my problem.

```
@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do your post stuff here
        pass
    else:
        c = {}
        c['form'] = RegistrationForm()
        c['context_instance'] = RequestContext(request)
        return render_to_response('registration/registerHome.html',c )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

```
from django.shortcuts import render
@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("firstname")
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get("lastname")
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password)
            user.first_name = first_name
            user.last_name = last_name
            user.set_password(password)
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/registerHome.html',dict(form=form) ) )
```

Comment: Could be error in the form and its not displaying in the template. Try printing the error after else block i.e `print form.errors`

Comment: Good!! Please upvote my answer so that it will be helpful to others. Thanks in advance.